# neo4j console slows down and becomes unresponsive in chrome browser after running a few queries

Tags: neo4j

I am running Neo4j on my localhost. My network is not big (674 nodes and 11324 relationships). After I run a few queries the console becomes slower and slower and at some point the hot key (up arrow) stops and I get unresponsive messages from chrome. When I close the page and start over everything is back to normal. Is this a memory leakage? or Is there something I need to do?

Comment: Same behavior in IE or firefox?

Comment: Firefox works fine, it is chrome

Comment: ...Chrome is a memory hog, just use another browser, problem solved, but what's this got to do with programming?

Comment: I was not sure it was a browser issue or software. Where would have been the right place to post it?